# LSTM+FFN performs more poorly than FFN

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am building several simple networks to predict the bike rentals at 500 stations in the upcoming hour, given rentals at all stations in the previous 24 hours. I am working with two architectures, one with a graph convolution (which amounts to updating each station with a learned linear combination of other stations, at each hour) and a FNN layer to prediction, and a second with a graph convolution -> LSTM -> FNN to prediction.

Before I describe more, I'm getting poorer performance for my model which includes an LSTM unit, which is confusing me.

See these two images for a description of each architecture, for each architecture I also add hourly meta-data (weather, time, etc) as variation, they are in the images in red, and not relevant to my question. Image links at the bottom of the post.
[Architecture 1: GCNN + FNN][1]
[Architecture 2: GCNN + LSTM + FNN][2]

Confusingly, the test RMSE for the first model is 3.46, for the second model its 3.57. Could someone please explain to me why the second wouldn't be lower, as it seems to be running the exact same processes, except with an additional LSTM unit.

Here are relevant snippets of my code for the GCNN+FNN model:

```
def gcnn_ddgf(hidden_layer, node_num, feature_in, horizon, learning_rate, beta, batch_size, early_stop_th, training_epochs, X_training, Y_training, X_val, Y_val, X_test, Y_test, scaler, display_step):

n_output_vec = node_num * horizon # length of output vector at the final layer 
early_stop_k = 0 # early stop patience
best_val = 10000
traing_error = 0
test_error = 0
pred_Y = []

tf.reset_default_graph()

batch_size = batch_size
early_stop_th = early_stop_th
training_epochs = training_epochs

# tf Graph input and output
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, node_num, feature_in]) # X is the input signal
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output_vec]) # y is the regression output

# define dictionaries to store layers weight & bias
weights_hidden = {}
weights_A = {}
biases = {}
vec_length = feature_in
weights_hidden['h1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vec_length, hidden_layer], stddev=0.5))
biases['b1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, hidden_layer], stddev=0.5))
weights_A['A1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_num, node_num], stddev=0.5))
    
weights_hidden['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_layer, horizon], stddev=0.5))
biases['bout'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, horizon], stddev=0.5))

# Construct model
pred= gcn(X, weights_hidden, weights_A, biases, node_num, horizon) #see below
pred = scaler.inverse_transform(pred)
Y_original = scaler.inverse_transform(Y)

cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred - Y_original, 2))) 
                           
#optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, decay).minimize(cost)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta1=beta).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        avg_cost_sq = 0.
        num_train = X_training.shape[0]
        total_batch = int(num_train/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_training[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,], 
                                                  Y: Y_training[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,]})

            avg_cost_sq += np.square(c) * batch_size #/ total_batch 
            
        # rest part of training dataset
        if total_batch * batch_size != num_train:
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_training[total_batch*batch_size:num_train,], 
                                      Y: Y_training[total_batch*batch_size:num_train,]})
            avg_cost_sq += np.square(c) * (num_train - total_batch*batch_size)
        
        avg_cost = np.sqrt(avg_cost_sq / num_train)
          
        # validation
        c_val, = sess.run([cost], feed_dict={X: X_val, Y: Y_val})
                                
        if c_val < best_val:
            # testing
            c_tes, preds, Y_true = sess.run([cost, pred, Y_original], feed_dict={X: X_test,Y: Y_test})
            best_val = c_val
            test_error = c_tes
            traing_error = avg_cost
            pred_Y = preds
            early_stop_k = 0 # reset to 0

        # update early stopping patience
        if c_val >= best_val:
            early_stop_k += 1

        # threshold
        if early_stop_k == early_stop_th:
            break
        
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "Training RMSE: ","{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("Validation RMSE: ", c_val)
            print("Lowest test RMSE: ", test_error)

    print("epoch is ", epoch)
    print("training RMSE is ", traing_error)
    print("Optimization Finished! the lowest validation RMSE is ", best_val)
    print("The test RMSE is ", test_error)

return best_val, pred_Y ,Y_true,test_error

# code that creates the model
def gcn(signal_in, weights_hidden, weights_A, biases, node_num, horizon):

signal_in = tf.transpose(signal_in, [1, 0, 2]) # node_num, batch, feature_in
feature_len = signal_in.shape[2] # feature vector length at the node of the input graph

signal_in = tf.reshape(signal_in, [node_num, -1]) # node_num, batch*feature_in

Adj = 0.5*(weights_A['A1'] + tf.transpose(weights_A['A1'])) 
Adj = normalize_adj(Adj)
Z = tf.matmul(Adj, signal_in) # node_num, batch*feature_in 
Z = tf.reshape(Z, [-1, int(feature_len)]) # node_num * batch, feature_in
signal_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(Z, weights_hidden['h1']), biases['b1'])
signal_output = tf.nn.relu(signal_output) # node_num * batch, hidden_vec

final_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(signal_output, weights_hidden['out']), biases['bout'])  # node_num * batch, horizon
# final_output = tf.nn.relu(final_output) 
final_output = tf.reshape(final_output, [node_num, -1, horizon]) # node_num, batch, horizon
final_output = tf.transpose(final_output, [1, 0, 2]) # batch, node_num, horizon
final_output = tf.reshape(final_output, [-1, node_num*horizon]) # batch, node_num*horizon

return final_output
```

And the code for the GCNN+LSTM+FNN model:

```
def gcnn_ddgf_lstm(node_num, feature_in, learning_rate, beta, batch_size, early_stop_th, training_epochs, X_training, 
               Y_training, X_val, Y_val, X_test, Y_test, scaler,  lstm_layer):
n_output_vec = node_num # length of output vector at the final layer 

early_stop_k = 0 # early stop patience
display_step = 1 # frequency of printing results
best_val = 10000
traing_error = 0
test_error = 0
predic_res = []

tf.reset_default_graph()

batch_size = batch_size
early_stop_th = early_stop_th
training_epochs = training_epochs

# tf Graph input and output
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, node_num, feature_in]) # X is the input signal
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output_vec]) # y is the regression output
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_layer, state_is_tuple=True)

# define dictionaries to store layers weight & bias
weights_hidden = {}
weights_A = {}
biases = {}

weights_A['A1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_num, node_num], stddev=0.5))  
weights_hidden['h1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([lstm_layer, node_num], stddev=0.5))
biases['h1'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, node_num], stddev=0.5))
weights_hidden['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_num, node_num], stddev=0.5))
biases['bout'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, node_num], stddev=0.5))

# Construct model
pred= gcn_lstm(X, weights_hidden, weights_A, biases, node_num, lstm_cell)
# pred = scaler.inverse_transform(pred)
# Y_original = scaler.inverse_transform(Y)

cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred - Y, 2)))              
      
#optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, decay).minimize(cost)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta1=beta).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        avg_cost_sq = 0.
        num_train = X_training.shape[0]
        total_batch = int(num_train/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_training[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,], 
                                                  Y: Y_training[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,]})

            avg_cost_sq += np.square(c) * batch_size #/ total_batch 
            
        # rest part of training dataset
        if total_batch * batch_size != num_train:
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_training[total_batch*batch_size:num_train,], 
                                      Y: Y_training[total_batch*batch_size:num_train,]})
            avg_cost_sq += np.square(c) * (num_train - total_batch*batch_size)
        
        avg_cost = np.sqrt(avg_cost_sq / num_train)

        # validation
        c_val, = sess.run([cost], feed_dict={X: X_val, Y: Y_val})
        
        if c_val < best_val:
            c_tes, preds = sess.run([cost, pred], feed_dict={X: X_test,Y: Y_test})
            best_val = c_val
            # save model
            #saver.save(sess, './bikesharing_gcnn_ddgf')
            test_error = c_tes
            traing_error = avg_cost
            early_stop_k = 0 # reset to 0

        # update early stopping patience
        if c_val >= best_val:
            early_stop_k += 1

        # threshold
        if early_stop_k == early_stop_th:
            pred_Y = scaler.inverse_transform(preds)
            Y_true = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test)
            test_err = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred_Y - Y_true, 2)))
            break

        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "Training RMSE: ","{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("Validation RMSE: ", c_val)
            print("Lowest test RMSE: ", test_error)
                    
    print("epoch is ", epoch)
    print("training RMSE is ", traing_error)
    print("Optimization Finished! the lowest validation RMSE is ", best_val)
    print("The scaled test RMSE is ", test_error)

return pred_Y, Y_true

def gcn_lstm(signal_in, weights_hidden, weights_A, biases, node_num, lstm_cell):

signal_in = tf.transpose(signal_in, [1, 0, 2]) # node_num, batch, feature_in
feature_len = signal_in.shape[2] # feature vector length at the node of the input graph
signal_in = tf.reshape(signal_in, [node_num, -1]) # node_num, batch*feature_in

Adj = 0.5*(weights_A['A1'] + tf.transpose(weights_A['A1'])) 
Adj = normalize_adj(Adj)
Z = tf.matmul(Adj, signal_in) # node_num, batch*feature_in 
Z = tf.reshape(Z, [node_num, -1, int(feature_len)]) # node_num, batch, feature_in
Z = tf.transpose(Z,[1,2,0]) # batch, feature_in, node_num
# init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
_, Z = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, Z, dtype = tf.float32) # init_state?

dense_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(Z[1], weights_hidden['h1']), biases['h1'])
dense_output = tf.nn.relu(dense_output)
final_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(dense_output, weights_hidden['out']), biases['bout'])  # batch, node_num*horizon
    
return final_output
```

In particular, should I be weary that  _, Z = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, Z, dtype = tf.float32) causes my variables defined elsewhere not to train?

Thanks a lot for any help :)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAO2t.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDjHw.png

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.
I have three years of bike use data to make the prediction, and was using the ~last three months as my validation/test set. The last few months were winter with lower bike use. I got expected results (GCNN+LSTM outperforms GCNN, though not by much) when I shuffled my training data prior to allocating to sets (with sequences preserved for LSTM)